# Match first instance that does not equal specified string

Tags: excel

How can I get the position of the first instance in a range that does not equal a specified string?

With the following content in cells A1:A5:

```
Yes
Yes
Hrmpf
Yes
No
```

I would like to get the value `3`.

My best (failed) attempt at solution was:

```
=MATCH("<>"&"YES",D8:D32,0)
```

which produces:

```
#N/A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this before using an array formula (which requires you to confirm it using CTRL+SHIFT+Enter).

`=MATCH(FALSE,A1:A6="Yes",0)`